# Getting Error while creating add-on heroku while adding Sendgrid starter plan

Tags: heroku

While creating sendgrid add-on to my application on heroku I am getting error from this morning that shows:

> An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create sendgrid:starter: Error Provisioning User - Whitelabel domain could not be located when creating customer".

Previously it was working fine. Now this. What may be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Looks like this is your first post. May I ask you to provide more details? Which environment do you use? I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm getting the same error on review apps right now. Seems like it might be a Sendgrid or Heroku error

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues with Sendgrid, randomly flagging my review app's account as abuse or spam, or disabling creation via Heroku — in all cases I just write to Heroku, they escalate it to Sendgrid, then they fix it.

It's annoying, but in the worst-case scenario, you can always create one "testing staging app" to hold Sendgrid and just share the credentials from that account via the shared configuration variables.